# How to make join query using silverlight and Domain context

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq

In ASP.Net we would write a join query for this but in silverlight join query are not  supported.

In SilverlightApplication.Xaml.cs

```
   private void btnreject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

        {

            DomainContext objectcontext=new DomainContext();    
            EMPLOYEE emp = new EMPLOYEE();    //EMPLOYEE is a Table name    
            string from = emp.EMPEMAIL;    
            string to = emp.EMP_EMPEMAIL;  //How To Get a To Address Here That is The Email id is  Based on Subcode in leave Table 

            if (DataGrid1.SelectedItem != null)    
            {   
                objectcontext.Load(this.objectcontext.GetLeaveCancellationQuery(Int32.Parse(WebContext.Current.User.Name))).Completed += new            EventHandler(LeaveApprovCancelApplication_Completed);    
                objectcontext.SubmitChanges();   
                objectcontext.sendemail(From,To);

            }

        }
```

**Table Structure:**

I have a Data Grid as follows:

```
CheckBoxField,EmployeeName, EmployeeId,LeaveStatus,SubCode    
* , XX , 1 , Pending ,2
```

and I have 2 tables They Are Employee table, and Leave Table...

Employee Table Have Following datafields:

```
Employee Id, EmployeeName,Email    
1 , XX ,x@g.c    
2 ,YY ,Y@g.c
```

Leave Table Have The Following Fields :

```
EmployeeId, EmployeeName, LeaveStatus, SubCode    
1 ,XX ,Pending ,2
```

And My DataGrid ItemSource = Leavetable
Am Using DomainServiceClass and Ado.NetDataEntityModel

When User Check The CheckBox In DataGrid And Click The Cancel Button. The Leavestatus Will Be UpDated As "Cancelled" And Mail Would Be Automatically Send To The Employee

In This The Mail FromAddress Would Be TakenBy EmployeeTable 
join by LeaveTable SubCode=EmployeeTable EmployeeID.Then The Email Address Of Equal To SubCode Will Be taken as To Address

How can i make it